# Does tangent cone of a set at a vertex x contain origin?

Tags: functional-analysis

In the definition of the tangent cone given by Prof. S. Kesavan's functional analysis (Definition 3.4.2, page-88), it says the tangent cone at x contains origin as well. For me, it is very much difficult to visualize origin in the tangent cone unless the vetex x is itself is the origin.

Comment: The tangent cone contains the zero vector by construction. Let what exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks, I understood the geometry of the tangent cone from its construction.